# How to align this span to the right of the div?

Tags: html, css

I have the following HTML:

```
<div class="title">
    <span>Cumulative performance</span>
    <span>20/02/2011</span>
</div>
```

with this CSS:

```
.title
{
    display: block;
    border-top: 4px solid #a7a59b;
    background-color: #f6e9d9;
    height: 22px;
    line-height: 22px;
    padding: 4px 6px;
    font-size: 14px;
    color: #000;
    margin-bottom: 13px;
    clear:both;
}
```

If you check this jsFiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/8JwhZ/

you can see that the Name & Date are stuck together. Is there a way that I can get the date to align to the right? I've tried `float: right;` on the second `<span>` but it screws up the style, and pushes the date outside of the enclosing div

Comment: Are you able to modify the HTML?

Comment: If you want something to float in relation to another object, the floater needs to be before the non-floater. Date should be before title and floating right.

Answer (score 313, accepted):

If you can modify the HTML: http://jsfiddle.net/8JwhZ/3/

```
<div class="title">
  <span class="name">Cumulative performance</span>
  <span class="date">20/02/2011</span>
</div>

.title .date { float:right }
.title .name { float:left }
```

Comment: CSS is simplified and proper clean: both should be added. Also fiddle contain very fragile solution: http://jsfiddle.net/8JwhZ/2090/

Comment: Or if you want it inline (i did) `<span style="float: right">`

Comment: float wraps when the window/div is too small to fit the contents. If that's a problem for you, use the display:flex solution by @Risord

Answer (score 75):

Working with floats is bit messy:

[image]

This as many other 'trivial' layout tricks  can be done with flexbox.

```
   div.container {
     display: flex;
     justify-content: space-between;
   }
```

In 2017 I think this is preferred solution (over float) if you don't have to support legacy browsers: https://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox

Check fiddle how different float usages compares to flexbox ("may include some competing answers"): https://jsfiddle.net/b244s19k/25/. If you still need to stick with float I recommended third version of course.

Comment: This is the one I opted to use, keep in mind to also set `float: left;` and `float: right;` in the spans containing the elements you want to space.

Comment: Core message of this answer is that "float are considered harmful" and you shouldn't ever use those (ok sure there are some rare exceptions).

So can you clarify why you think that's a good idea?

Comment: I thought `float` was required in the inner elements because I thought it is defined in the fiddle example for them, but for `#testD` it is not defined. My bad!

Answer (score 31):

An alternative solution to floats is to use absolute positioning:

```
.title {
  position: relative;
}

.title span:last-child {
  position: absolute;
  right: 6px;   /* must be equal to parent's right padding */
}
```

See also [the fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/philippm/2TrLr/).

Answer (score 12):

The solution using flexbox without `justify-content: space-between`.

```
<div class="title">
  <span>Cumulative performance</span>
  <span>20/02/2011</span>
</div>

.title {
  display: flex;
}

span:first-of-type {
  flex: 1;
}
```

When we use `flex:1` on the first `<span>`, it takes up the entire remaining space and moves the second `<span>` to the right. The Fiddle with this solution: https://jsfiddle.net/2k1vryn7/

Here https://jsfiddle.net/7wvx2uLp/3/ you can see the difference between two flexbox approaches: flexbox with `justify-content: space-between` and flexbox with `flex:1` on the first `<span>`.

Answer (score 5):

You can do this without modifying the html. 
http://jsfiddle.net/8JwhZ/1085/

```
<div class="title">
<span>Cumulative performance</span>
<span>20/02/2011</span>
</div>

.title span:nth-of-type(1) { float:right }
.title span:nth-of-type(2) { float:left }
```

Answer (score -2):

```
ul { /** works with ol too **/
    list-style: none; /** removes bullet points/numbering **/
    padding-left: 0px; /** removes actual indentation **/
}
```

Comment: Seems like an answer for a different question