# Left & Right justified text on one line

Tags: html, css

I had a question about right & left justified text as eloquently illustrated by Phrogz here:

[How to align this span to the right of the div?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5067279/how-to-align-this-span-to-the-right-of-the-div)

http://jsfiddle.net/8JwhZ/3/

The behavior when the window becomes too small is that when the two `<div>` tag touch each other the right justified text gets bumped down to the next line.

Is there another way to code this so they stay on the same line?  for instance in the above example when the second `<div>` tag touches I'd like it to stop moving and the window close over it.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to align this span to the right of the div?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5067279/how-to-align-this-span-to-the-right-of-the-div)

Comment: @JukkaK.Korpela Negative... this question is supplementary to, not duplicate of, the question you referred to.  Please ensure you understand the question at hand before making suggestions.

Comment: for positioning purpose u can use float attribute
and for your ur resizing prob lem u can make your parent div to be relative in position attribute.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option would be to append a `min-width` attribute to your `.title`

```
.title
{
    min-width: 300px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/8JwhZ/469/

Does that address your question sufficiently or did you have something else in mind?

Comment: YES!  Thank you!  that's exactly the behavior I was trying to get.

Answer (score 2):

as @Mike mentioned we can give

> min-width:xxxpx;

or else

Try

> position:fixed;

in each span than will solve your problem

Answer (score 0):

Not really, if I understand your question. You can't exactly make it look good after the screen gets too small, unless you use absolute positioning.

Answer (score 0):

yes you can add min-width and min-height property to position your place of the menu

> .heading
>       {
>        min-width:200px;
>        min-height:100px;
>        }

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

.title {overflow: hidden;}

The whole point of hidden is to prevent this, instead of trying to accommodate overflow, this property pretty much ignores it and lets it be hidden on the screen.